# Porque minha imagem não aparece ao executar o app?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, imageview

Tenho o seguinte código xml no Android Studio:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width = "match_parent"
          android:layout_height = "match_parent"
          android:orientation = "vertical"
          android:weightSum = "1">

<ImageView
    app:srcCompat = "@mipmap/logon_img"
    android:id = "@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_gravity = "center_horizontal"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_weight = "0.38"
    android:layout_height = "100dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id = "@+id/login"
    android:layout_gravity = "center_horizontal"
    android:textSize = "30sp"
    android:textAlignment = "center"
    android:textStyle = "normal|bold"
    android:textColor = "@color/Red"
    android:text = "@string/typeUserName"
    android:layout_weight = "0.00"
    android:layout_width = "350dp"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:inputType = "textPersonName"
    android:ems = "10"
    android:id = "@+id/account"
    android:layout_gravity = "center_horizontal"
    android:textAlignment = "center"
    android:textSize = "20sp"
    android:layout_width = "300dp"
    tools:ignore = "LabelFor"/>

<TextView
    android:text = "@string/password"
    android:layout_width = "350dp"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:id = "@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_weight = "0.00"
    android:layout_gravity = "center_horizontal"
    android:textSize = "30sp"
    android:textAlignment = "center"
    android:textStyle = "normal|bold"
    android:textColor = "@color/Red"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width = "300dp"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:inputType = "textPassword"
    android:ems = "10"
    android:id = "@+id/password"
    android:layout_gravity = "center_horizontal"
    android:textAlignment = "center"
    android:textSize = "20sp"
    tools:ignore = "LabelFor"/>

<Button
    android:text = "@android:string/ok"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:id = "@+id/button"
    android:layout_gravity = "center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width = "200dp"
    android:textSize = "20sp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

O componente em questão é o ImageView, ele simplesmente não aparece no emulador e nem no meu celular, porém, há um espaço vazio reservado pra ele na tela. Procurei o problema várias vezes e na grande maioria delas era o tamanho enorme da imagem, que não é meu caso pois seu tamanho é de 256x256. Segue um screenshot do emulador e do layout.

> minSdkVersion 19
> targetSdkVersion 25
> com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0

[image: SS do emulador]
[image: SS do layout]

Comment: Testei o seu layout e ele foi correctamente apresentado. Indique na pergunta qual o mín,máx e target api e a versão da appcompat.

Comment: Apesar de não encontrar justificação para isso tente substituir `app:srcCompat = "@mipmap/logon_img"` por `android:src = "@mipmap/logon_img"`.

Comment: `android:src` foi a solução @ramaral, mt obrigado! Agr vou procurar o porque disso acontecer

Comment: Responda por favor ao meu primeiro comentário, acrescente a versão do Android do dispositivo/emulador onde testou. Isso ajudará a encontrar uma justificação.

Comment: Alterei a pergunta, veja se é isso mesmo que precisa saber ou se esta precisando de mais alguma informação.

Comment: Não, você está a usar versões recentes. Não encontro explicação, deveria funcionar com qualquer um dos atributos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Testei o seu layout e ele foi correctamente apresentado.

A única coisa que veja que possa estar a criar o problema é o uso do atributo `app:srcCompat`.
Apesar da razão principal da existência do atributo `app:srcCompat` ser possibilitar o uso de *VectorDrawable* em versões mais antigas do Android, ele também (deveria) suporta(r) o uso de bitmaps.

Assim, substitua

```
app:srcCompat = "@mipmap/logon_img"
```

por

```
android:src = "@mipmap/logon_img"
```

Se `@mipmap/logon_img` é um VectorDrawable veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/182187/2541)

Answer (score 2):

Já tive alguns problemas com imagens no android, muitos deles desapareceram com a utilização de uma biblioteca chamada **picasso**.

Esta situação ocorre pela proporção da imagem não estar "cabendo" dentro do tamanho do layout, nas linhas:

```
android:layout_width = "match_parent"
android:layout_weight = "0.38"
android:layout_height = "100dp"
```

Vc pode tentar "encaixar" a imagem diminuindo a resolução dela, com o uso de ferramentas como o [resize](http://www.picresize.com/) (ferramenta gratuita e online). Ou alterar o tamanho no próprio layout.

Mas eu te oriento a tentar implementar o **picasso**. Para isto basta inserir nas dependências do `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
.
.
.
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
}
```

Retire a linha `app:srcCompat = "@mipmap/logon_img"` do *xml* e em sua `Activity` dentro do `onCreate`, insira a linha:

```
Picasso.with(getApplication()).load(R.mipmap.logo_img).resize(256, 256).centerCrop().into(imageView);
```

Caso não funcione, a imagem pode ficar muito maior do que vc gostaria ou nem aparecer, dentro do `.resize(x,y)` vc poderá colocar uma proporção para encaixar a sua imagem no layout.

Comment: Não será exagerado usar um biblioteca apenas para redimensionar uma imagem de 256x256. Caso seja um problema do tamanho da imagem(o que não acredito) não seria melhor, já que ela é colocada na pasta mipmap, redimensioná-la num programa de edição de imagens?

Comment: Sim, se ele for utilizar apenas uma imagem no aplicativo. Com o decorrer de desenvolvimento, acredito que ele tenha que reutilizar do mesmo processo.

Comment: O ideal seria criar todas as imagens com todos os tamanhos corretos e aconselho a criar esses tamanhos diferentes no `mipmap`. Porém, mais uma vez, se será uma única imagem por que não utilizar a biblioteca? Ela não deixará a aplicação lenta. Nos meus projetos, não tive problemas com esta implementação, pelo contrário, o resultado é muito mais rápido e satisfatório.

Comment: Não digo que o uso da biblioteca não seja útil em determinadas situações. Apenas digo que não o é em casos semelhantes a este, casos em que se está a utilizar *icons* e não fotografias. Além que tenho quase a certeza que o problema do AP nada tem haver com o tamanho da imagem já que ela tem 256x256.

Comment: Esta resolução da imagem pode ou não se encaixar no layout do AP.Vai depender muito da densidade que o aparelho têm, para o tamanho da imagem ser exibida.Infelizmente, o android não facilita muito para isso, o [android_developer](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html) sempre indica o uso dos `mipmaps`, já que o android não converte diretamente pixels por dpi, vc precisa fazer isto manualmente.Tanto que foi minha primeira orientação, na resposta, em redimensionar esta imagem.O problema é: ele terá de criar todos as dimensões possíveis e inserí-las em cada pasta