# Erro ao tentar exibir uma imageView vetorial (SVG)!

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, imageview, android-resources

Bom galera, nesse app pretendo fazer um teste inserindo uma imagem vetorial na activity principal.

Fiz o processo de integração todo certinho, como podem ver:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas mesmo tendo seguido todo o tutorial, o seguinte erro que aparece, de forma que não dá nem para executar o app:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**MainActivity:**

```js
package genesysgeneration.ruleoftree;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVG;
import com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVGParser;

public class Main01Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private EditText et01, et02, et03;
    private TextView tv01, tvTest;
    private double l01, l02, l03, equalizer, lxx;
    private Button btnChange01, btnCompras, btnMoeda;
    private ImageView logo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main01);

        logo.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromAsset(getResources(), R.raw.tree);
        logo.setImageDrawable(svg.createPictureDrawable());
        setContentView(logo);

        tvTest=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTest);
        tv01=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv01);
        tvTest.setText(String.valueOf(0));
        tv01.setText(String.valueOf(0));

    }
  
}
```

OBS - Não transcrevi todo o código como devem ter percebido, pois não há necessidade, já que o restante está funfando liso.

Tutorial em questão (vídeo) => [Integrate SVG](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S65WtImJOvI) => (site) [Android Coffe](http://android-coffee.com/svg-integration-in-android-studio/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nas versões mais recentes do Android Studio é possível usar arquivos SVG sem recorrer a bibliotecas externas.

Clique com o botão direito do rato em cima da pasta *drawable* e no menu que abre, escolha ***new->Vector Asset***.

Na janela escolha **Local file (SVG, PSD)**, indique o caminho para o arquivo, clique <kbd>next</kbd> e depois <kbd>finish</kbd> na janela seguinte.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
<sup>Fonte: [documentação android](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html#importing)</sup>

Este procedimento cria um arquivo xml([VectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html)) que pode ser usado como qualquer outro *icon*.

---

**Nota 1:**

Para usar VectorDrawable em versões inferiores ao Android 5.0 (API level 21) é necessário a Support Library 23.2.0 e configurar o *build.gradle* da seguinte forma:

```
//For Gradle Plugin 2.0+
 android {
   defaultConfig {
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
 }
```

e em vez de `android:src` deverá usar `android:srcCompat`.
Veja a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html#vector-drawables-backward-solution) para informação mais completa.

Conforme salientado pelo @rsicarelli, a partir da versão [23.4.0](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/rev-archive.html#rev23-4-0) da Support Library é necessário explicitamente fazer o *enable* da funcionalidade colocando

```
static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromSourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

no topo da Activity.

**Nota 2:**

Nas versões mais recentes da Support Library(25.1.1 nesta data), desde que não se preocupe em que a APK tenha mais alguns Kbs, não é necessário aplicar o descrito na nota 1.
O Android Studio gera um PNG por cada VectorDrawable para ser utilizado nas versões inferiores à 21.

**Nota 3**

A retro-compatibilidade nem sempre é garantida.

[Este *post*](https://medium.com/@ferrand.d/can-you-and-should-you-use-vector-drawables-a-cheatsheet-32a2e1cc2ecf#.ukcx7jwyv) explica em forma de diagrama o descrito nas notas.

Comment: A partir da versão `23.4.0` é necessário adicionar a lista `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);` no topo da sua `Activity` para ter suporte para a API <21. Ref https://goo.gl/HL8wVw

Comment: @rsicarelli A [documentação/guia](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html#vector-drawables-backward-solution) não faz referência a isso, no entanto há essa indicação na [Revision 23.4.0](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/rev-archive.html#rev23-4-0). Fiquei sem perceber se `setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)` substitui `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` ou se é necessário usar os dois.

Comment: Realmente a documentação não deixa isso claro, porém os dois métodos são necessários.

Comment: Muito obrigado galera!!! Agora quando tento colocar esse SVG como logo do app aparece uma imagem nada a ver (nativa do android)... Poderia resolver por aqui ou devo fazer uma nova pergunta já que minha questão já foi resolvida?

Answer (score 3):

Provavelmente esse erro se de porque voce etá tentando pegar o arquivo como um item do assets "**SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromAsset(getResources(), R.raw.tree);**",mas provavelmente a pasta assets não tenha sido definida, para criar ela, clique com o direito do mouse em project e escolha new/folder/assets folder.

tenta assim ó:

```
//...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main01);

    logo.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    // SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromAsset(getResources(), R.raw.tree);
    // melhor voce criar uma pasta assets, copiar o arquivo para ela e usar 
    final SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromAsset(getAssets(), "tree.svg");
    logo.setImageDrawable(svg.createPictureDrawable());
    //setContentView(logo);
    // desnecessario essa linha
}
//...
```

e nunca é recomendado ter o nome de uma activity com numero ou letras maiusculas, assim, se possivel, renomeie a mesma para outro nome que contenha somente letras.

Comment: mudei, errei. era para ser SVG svg = **SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.tree);** agora dá para executar, mas o app para do nada. olharei o android monitor

Comment: deu uma exceção com oq vc me indicou fazer, irei colocá-la

Comment: se vc manja de ingles, vai aqui ó: http://blog.fordemobile.com/2013/01/display-svg-inside-imageview.html