# Não consigo definir uma imagem vetorial como ícone do aplicativo

Tags: android, svg, icons

Como podem ver as adicionei corretamente uma **imagem.svg** de forma que ela age de maneira vetorial:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema acontece quando tento colocá-la como ícone do aplicativo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu vou no AndroidManifest.xml e modifico normalmente a linha `android:icon="@drawable/ic_tree"` assim como faço com um **drawable** normal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="genesysgeneration.svg">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_tree"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Pensei que teria que fazer algo diferente depois que vi que não deu certo, porém **o aplicativo não me dá outras escolhas:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei colocar a imagem dentro da pasta mipmap como me indicaram, porém deu erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cria a pasta mipmap e coloque o ícone la. É o novo padrão Android.

Comment: Apresentou um erro... Editei a pergunta apresentando-o.

Comment: Bom vou tentar depois, nunca tentei usar vetor no mipmap.
Mas é certo que o android adota esse novo padrão.

Comment: Qual é o `minSdkVersion` e a `targetSdkVersion` para a aplicação? Qual é a versão do android que está a correr no emulador?

Comment: 15 e 25 respectivamente... (4.0.3 ice cream sand...) e (7.1 nougat)

Comment: Testei na 9, 16 e 25 e funciona. Actualize/Utilize as versões mais recentes do Android Studio, Build Tools, build:gradle tools e Support Library.

Comment: atualizei o android studio, o erro ao colocar no mipmap sumiu, porém mesmo assim não exibe o icone correto

Comment: gostaria de utilizar a API 15 mesmo, pois estou mais habituado a mesma e é a partir dela que há a maior parte dos usuários.

Comment: Na resposta que lhe dei à sua pergunta [Erro ao tentar exibir uma imageView vetorial (SVG)!](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182156/2541) não use o que é descrito na Nota 1, veja a Nota 2.

Comment: Por favor poste o arquivo do ícone, para assim realizar um teste aqui. Pra poder te ajudar...

Comment: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/tree-svg

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim salve o arquivo na pasta drawable depois click com o direito do mouse e crie um Vector Asset:

[image: Vector Asset]

---

Outro modo!

Bem... pra facilitar existe este site "Dentro no link .txt"  que converte qualquer imagem em icon do Andoid Studio.

Anexo: [Arquivos](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9UeCCws7oxXM0Z3QXZ6bVNpazQ)

Vou explicar como fiz:

1. Baixei o seu arquivo (.svg) como png.
2. Fui no site que passei e upei a imagem.
3. Defini o fundo nulo (transparente).
4. Salvei... no qual gerou um ZIP (com uma pasta res)
5. Depois substitui no projeto nas pastas mipmap: (ver anexo a imagem do projeto)
6. Gerando este resultado: (ver no anexo a print do emulador)

Qualquer dúvida pode perguntar!!!

Comment: fiz isso man e nn resultou

Comment: tbm tentei criar o xml no mipmap, porém ele cria direto no drawable

Comment: sobre o svg, crie-o no drawable, porém acusou um erro e fui obrigado a colocá-lo na pasta raw

Comment: adicionei um novo metodo na resposta (edit)

Comment: opa, eu tenho essa mesma imagem em png, gostaria mesmo de saber se dá para colocá-la como ícone do app sendo svg

Comment: Então eu tentei naquele site o SVG que você mandou porem ele corta a imagem acredito que esta muito alto a resolução... dá olhada aqui -> [link] (https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html) .

Comment: simsim, pensei nisso por causa das resoluções diferentes entre aparelhos